# JavaScript deadlock

Tags: javascript, deadlock, infinite-loop

[Here](http://webreflection.blogspot.de/2007/06/simplest-javascript-deadlock.html) I saw JavaScript deadlocks and this code:

```
var loop = true,
block = setTimeout(function(){loop = false}, 1);
while(loop);
```

It's definitely infinite loop and causes to browser freezing. It's said that `deadlock is created when one operation wait another one to be executed and vice-versa`. 
 My question is, except that, what kind of situations deadlock occurs and the ways to avoid them?

Comment: `setTimeout` is meant to deal with exactly these obsolete code constructions where one would waste some number of cycles to make it run slower. Computers even have hardware schedulers that do this on a hardware level so that the CPU can sleep a bit and save power.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's not a deadlock, just an infinite loop, you can't have a deadlock in JavaScript as you can't have more than one thread accessing your data.

What happens here is that as your loop never ends and the js engine being mono-thread (regarding your script), the scheduler never calls the callback you give to `setTimeout`. In fact you would have had exactly the same behavior without the second line.

Answer (score 11):

Javascript *can* deadlock, parallel execution is not a necessary condition of deadlock.  the javascript VM is single threaded, but it has a concurrent execution paradigm so the Coffman conditions can be met:

Here is an example:

```js
function makeFuture() {
  let resolve;
  let reject;
  let promise = new Promise((d, e) => {
    resolve = d;
    reject = e;
  });
  return [promise, resolve, reject];
}

class Lock {
  constructor() {
    this.q = [];
    this.running = false;
  }
  async runQueue() {
    if (this.running) return;
    this.running = true;
    while (this.q.length > 0) {
      const { asyncFunction, resolve, reject } = this.q.shift();
      try {
        let result = await asyncFunction();
        resolve(await asyncFunction());
      } catch (error) {
        reject(error);
      }
    }
    this.running = false;
  }
  runTask(asyncFunction) {
    const [promise, resolve, reject] = makeFuture();
    this.q.push({ asyncFunction, resolve, reject });
    this.runQueue();
    return promise;
  }
}

const dbLock = new Lock();

let taskResultPromise = dbLock.runTask(async () => {
  console.log('about to deadlock');
  let value = await dbLock.runTask(async () => { return 'value'; });
  value //?
  console.log('did not deadlock');
  return value;
});
```

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) the Coffman conditions for deadlock are:

1. Mutual exclusion - The Lock class ensures exclusive concurrent access to a database resource.  The resources are (database lock, 'value' value)
2. Hold and wait - task 1 holds the db lock and waits for 'value' from task 2.  task 2 holds the 'value' and waits for the db lock
3. No preemption - the javascript JVM has no mechanism to force either task to release their lock preemptively.
4. Circular wait - see (2).